# Removing Substrings from List

Tags: c#

I have a list of palindromes

```
List<string> palindromes = new List<string>() 
{
    hijkllkjih,
    ijkllkji,
    jkllkj,
    kllk,
    ll,
    defggfed,
    efggfe,
    fggf,
    gg,
    abccba, 
    bccb,
    cc,
    qrrq, 
    rr,
    mnnm, 
    nn,
    pop, 
    o,
    s, 
    q,
    r
};
```

But I want to remove palindromes that are substring of other palindromes. So, the list would become

```
List<string> palindromes = new List<string>() 
{
    hijkllkjih,
    defggfed,
    abccba, 
    qrrq, 
    mnnm, 
    pop, 
    s, 
    q,
    r
};
```

To do this I have written the following code

```
List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < palindromes.Count; ++i)
{
    if (indexList.Contains(i))
        continue;

    string tmp = palindromes[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < palindromes.Count; ++j)
    {
        if (i == j 
            || indexList.Contains(j) 
            || palindromes[j].Length > palindromes[i].Length)
            continue;

        if (tmp.Contains(palindromes[j]))
            indexList.Add(j);
    }
}

foreach (var index in indexList.OrderByDescending(l => l))
    palindromes.RemoveAt(index);
```

Can this be improved?

Comment: What is `.Sequence`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the code a simple as possible by removing the class structure. Now it should make sense...

Comment: _I tried to make the code a simple as possible_ this is never a good idea because most probably you're going to get answers suggesting things that you already have and you'll answer that you already implemented the idea etc etc, normally a waste of time ;-) so please post your real code.

Comment: I suppose the expected result you've described is wrong since `q` is substring of `qrrq` so must be removed as well as `r`.

Comment: The palindroms are not strings so technically your code is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code to this:

```
var palindromesCopy = palindromes.ToList();
palindromes.RemoveAll(x => palindromesCopy.Any(y => x != y &&
                                               y.Contains(x)));
```

If you want to remove duplicated strings as said by @MoonKnight in comments, just call `Distinct` on `palindromes` after removing.

Comment: if I had two entries for "hijkllkjih" say, this would not remove one of them. We need extra logic in this case...

Comment: @MoonKnight I've added the comment in my answer describing "extra logic" :)

Comment: Worth mentioning, that while this solution is short and simple, it is `O(n^2)`. This looks like an interview/homework question, so you might want to consider more efficient (and less pretty) approaches.